# Building a UI for specific iPhone screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode

I've done a bit of research on this but everything I come across is either about Size Classes or Auto Layout.

The question: Is it possible to select a specific iPhone screen size to build a UI for? Specifically could I select the iPhone 5s size, build the UI then select the iPhone 6s size and build the UI for that size ect. Or do I have to use size classes to build "One UI for all sizes"?

Comment: Yes, you can build separate layout for different screen size using multiple storyboards. However, this is discouraged as if new devices are introduced, you have to create 1 more set of layout. Try your best to use Auto Layout, Size Classes, and Stack View (iOS 9+)

Comment: Take a new viewController for each size in same storyboard. Assign same class to each viewController and assign unique Storyboard ID to each viewController. When you want to call it then just check condition for identify device and call viewcontroller base on Storyboard ID.